# Need help interpreting this sed command

Tags: oracle, sed

I'm looking through an [Oracle script I found online](http://www.ixora.com.au/scripts/sql/multiblock_read_test.sql), but it runs a sed command to filter results from a trace file. I'm running Oracle on a Windows server, so the sed command isn't recognized.

```
host sed -n '/scattered/s/.*p3=//p' &Trace_Name | sort -n | tail -1
```

I've tried reading the [online documentation](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), but am still not sure how to interpret what this command is trying to filter. Would anyone be so kind as to help me interpret what this command is trying to filter? Or better yet, what I can run from a Windows command prompt to achieve the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says "on lines that contain 'scattered' replace zero or more of any character followed by 'p3=' with nothing (delete it, in other words) and print the result" (`-n` says don't print lines unless there's an explicit print command).

For this example input:

```
abc organized p3=123
def scattered p3=456
ghi ordered p3=789
```

The output would be:

```
456
```

Comment: For a DB FILE SCATTERED READ, p3 represents "The number of blocks that the session is trying to read from the file"

Comment: @Gary: After a while and much searching, I finally figured that part out. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

The sed command is searching a file for strings that match a pattern. The "-n" option will suppress output that is not explicitly printed. The "p" at the end says to print the lines that match the preceding pattern.

sort -n does a numerical sort.

tail -1 prints the last line, only.

So, it seems to be searching for scattered disk reads and printing the line with the biggest value.

I think the regular expression pattern is eliminating everything up to and including "p3=".   The s/from/to/" is a substitute command.

Answer (score 1):

The sed command works with cygwin, a unix-like shell for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

To address the other part of your question, the unxutils project ports many GNU utilities to Win32, including `sed`.  [Find out more](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).